How to configure Websockets across a JHipster Gateway Microservices setup?
I'm working on a project created with JHipster, using a Gateway-Microservices architecture. My goal is to configure a WebSocket connection across the entire system to enable real-time communication, such as a chat system or popup notifications sent to users.
Unfortunately, I've encountered some difficulties with my attempts to integrate Websockets into this setup and haven't been able to make it work.
Could someone explain if and how a WebSocket connection can be properly configured across the whole JHipster Gateway-Microservices setup? Are there specific configuration steps or best practices I should follow? Has anyone successfully implemented a real-time communication system in this architecture?
I tried configuring WebSockets in the JHipster Gateway and in the microservices themselves. I expected to establish a seamless real-time communication channel across the system, enabling features like chat or notifications. However, the WebSocket connections either didn't work as expected, or I encountered issues with routing the connections properly through the Gateway.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I don't think WebSockets work with WebFlux yet in JHipster. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14567
